# Como llamar un procedimiento almacenado usando Laravel con SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, laravel-8, laragon

Tengo una aplicación web donde quiero llamar un procedimiento almacenado en SQL Server, estoy usando Laragon para poder correr Laravel, cuando ya realice toda la conexión hice pruebas con select para traer información y si me la encuentra, pero al momento de querer traer el procedimiento almacenado sale que lo encuentra pero nunca corre lo que esta dentro de el, no crea el Backup en la carpeta especificada de misma manera que no hace el insert en la tabla que se especifica.

Realmente no entiendo si tiene algo que ver con Laragon debido a que sino mal entiendo funciona aislado al sistema, aunque creo que no deberia tener problemas por que todo se ejecuta desde SQL Server si es llamado correctamente o asi lo entiendo realmente soy algo nuevo en esto. Dato curioso si ejecuto el procedimiento desde SQL Server con el usuario SA si me crea el backup de la misma manera que hace el insert que especifico en este.

Quisiera entender porque no se ejecuta lo que esta en mi procedimiento y si es algún tema de configuración o permisos de laravel/laragon

Tengo el siguiente procedimiento almacenado en sql server.

```
create PROCEDURE BackupSeguridad
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @BackupPath NVARCHAR(500);
    DECLARE @Mensaje NVARCHAR(MAX);

    SET @BackupPath = 'C:/Respaldo_Seguridad_Completos/' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(20), GETDATE(), 112) + '_' +
                     REPLACE(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(20), GETDATE(), 108), ':', '') + '_Full.bak';
    BACKUP DATABASE securitycontrol
    TO DISK = @BackupPath
    WITH NOFORMAT, INIT, STATS = 10;

    SET @Mensaje = 'Respaldo completo de la base de datos Seguridad completado.';
    

    INSERT INTO RespaldosCompletos (FechaRespaldo, RutaRespaldo)
    VALUES (GETDATE(), @BackupPath);

    PRINT @Mensaje;
END
```

Esta es la configuracion que uso para hacer la conexion en laravel

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi ruta

```
Route::get('/Ejecutar-backup', [BackupController::class, 'ejecutarBackup']);
```

Y este es mi controlador que uso para llamar al procedimiento almacenado

```
 <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class BackupController extends Controller
{
    public function ejecutarBackup()
    {
        try{

        $respaldos = DB::statement('EXEC BackupSeguridad');
        return $respaldos;
       
        } catch(\Exception $e){

            return "Error al ejecutar el procedimiento almacenado: " . $e->getMessage();

        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Por favor no publiques código o mensajes de error/trazas de pila en imágenes, publica directamente el texto del código, el texto de los errores y los _stack traces_. Esto hace que sea menos complicado, para quien quiera ayudarte, investigar sobre el tema y hacer sus propias pruebas/adaptaciones al código, al escribir una respuesta y de esa forma aumenta tus posibilidades de encontrar la ayuda que buscas. Un saludo.

Comment: ¿Has intentado con `DB::select('EXEC BackupSeguridad')`?

Comment: Claro, me genera un error que me dice que no puedo ejecutar Select porque no devuelve ningún valor.

El siguiente es el mensaje que me manda

...

Error al ejecutar el procedimiento de copia de seguridad: SQLSTATE[IMSSP]: The active result for the query contains no fields. (Connection: sqlsrv, SQL: EXEC BackupSeguridad)

...

No entiendo realmente si se deba a permisos por parte de laravel, pero no creo que se deba a eso porque el backup lo corre desde SQL server, lo que si entiendo es que si encuentra el procedimiento, solamente no crea el archivo ni hace el insert que le asigno